# Would it make sense to move the "capital" of Europe away from Brussels?

Tags: european-union, brexit

Brussels, while not officially the capital of Europe, is *de facto* considered as such. The European Union has expanded eastward considerably in the last few decades and England has exited the EU. In this scenario, Brussels is not as central anymore (geographically and demographically) as it used to be.

In this context, would it make sense to move the seat of the EU institutions now in Brussels (at least some of them) to a place that reflects more the current center of the union (Vienna, Prague, somewhere else)? Do EU rules allow for such an event? Is any political entity proposing it?

Comment: Why does the capital need to be in a central location? That and where it should be seems like it would be largely opinion based.

Comment: It seems to me that it is a desiderable criteria for a capital. Why would somebody want a capital far away from its citizens/areas?

Comment: VTC because "effort to promote particular cause"; but you should probably research (or possibly ask a question about) why the institutions are where they are. To the best of my knowledge, there is a historical and symbolic reason why they tend to be in those places where Germanic-speaking Europe and Romance-speaking Europe border each other.

Comment: @pinpon it's [not unusual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C.) for the capital to [not be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow) in [the center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin).

Comment: @wonderbear Of course it is not just a geographical matter, but this is not the point of the question.

Comment: @tim still it would be probably be a desiderable criteria.

Comment: @pinpon why? And why would it be so important that it is worth moving the capital for? Which is generally a costly and rare action.

Comment: @tim Cause so the citizen would be closer to the institutions. Weather it is worth moving is exactly the point of the question.

Comment: Based on all the comments this appears to be a push question looking for a specific answer as all the explanations about a capital not needing to be in the geographic center seem to be ignored.

Comment: @Joe W It seems to me that all the comments do not acknowledge that being central geographically is probably a desiderable quality for a capital. Therefore simply ignoring the problem at the core of the question.

Comment: The question is whether it is necessarily desirable. A centrally located capital may be in an inhospitable part of the country (imagine Cairo or Canberra in the middle of the desert); a region without enough of an economy or infrastructure to effectively support the operations of the government; geographically indefensible or sub-optimally far from a major enemy nation (which might in fact be the case in the EU, where the government probably wants to be far from Russia); isolated from major maritime trade possibilities, and so on.

Comment: @pinpon There are many capitals around the world at various level of government that are not only nowhere close to the geographical center but they are actually close to a border. There are many reasons to choose a capital that have nothing to do with the geographical center especially as that can change over time as borders change. In the case of the EU that is because new countries get admitted and that changes what the center is.

Comment: @Olbie I would say that while not being the sole criteria it is a desiderable thing. About the inhospitability/economy capability it seems to me that most of Europe is fit in this sense. Regarding the defensibility this indeed sounds like a thing to consider in the European case.

Comment: @JoeW As I already told you, I get there are many other factor in play. The question is about one of the many factor that could be considered and how much weight it should be given. The borders can change up to a certain limit since Europe is geographically a limited entity.

Comment: And you are missing the common question which is why does the geographical center have anything to do with the location of the capital as it has been mentioned there are many places where that is and will never be true.

Comment: The fact that many capitals are not in the geographical center does not mean it is not a desiderable quality. It just mean that other factor prevailed/ were more important. From a organizational point of view I would say it is desiderable quality: it is easier on average for people to get there. Would you disagree?

Comment: @JoeW Perhaps the questioner thinks that the capital of the USA should be moved from Washington DC to Belle Fourche, South Dakota - the approximate centre of the country. Do you think the OP has the slightest idea of what it would cost in euros to move the EU institutions? When the Federal German Government decided after 1990 to move the capital to Berlin the cost and disruption was such that many Germans later argued it had been madness.

Comment: @tim Washington was near the center of the US when its site was selected for that reason.  The US then expanded westward.  Moscow was central in the Grand Duchy of Moscow and remained the center of power as the duchy expanded mostly eastward, eventually becoming the Russian Empire and its successor states. Berlin was central in Prussia, which in contrast to the other examples lost territory, mostly in the east. So all of these examples actually support the proposition that the preferred location for a capital is central, but historical circumstances can obscure this fact.

Comment: @phoog And when London became the capital of England, I believe under the Romans, it was far more central than it is today in respect to the United Kingdom. Though there is a small amount of political weight behind moving it - northwards. At some point parliament is going to have to move out of the present Palace of Westminster, for about 7 or 8 years, in order to do essential refurbishment - in short, it is falling down.  But the latest idea I've heard is that a temprary home be created on a floating pontoon on the Thames alongside the present building.

Answer (score 6):

***Would it make sense to move the seat of the EU institutions now in Brussels (at least some of them) to a place that reflects more the current center of the union (Vienna, Prague, somewhere else)?***

Some countries do consider a central location for their capital:

> Location is often key. Many countries choose a geographically central capital in order to emphasize the equity of their government; this way, the capital isn’t as likely to be, or seem to be, biased toward one region or another. Madrid, for instance, is located almost exactly in the middle of Spain (and, to take it one step further, the middle of the Iberian Peninsula). When Nigeria decided to build a brand-new capital city, it placed Abuja, which was formally named the capital in 1991, in the center—a place signifying unity in a country often considered divided by its geography.

*Source*: [How Do Countries Choose Their Capital Cities?](https://www.britannica.com/story/how-do-countries-choose-their-capital-cities)

So your idea is not without merits. But does the merits outweigh the cons? For EU, the concerns and considerations for identifying a capital was quite different:

> Brussels is neither the capital of Europe nor of the EU. The EU covers a network of national capitals that are inclined to compete instead of cooperate with one another. This is the reason Brussels was chosen in the first place, as the perfect compromise between large capitals that are not prepared to transfer their national power to *rival* capitals and therefore prefer weaker cities instead. Brussels, Strasbourg, Luxembourg, Munich and Franfurt are seats of EU institutions halfway between Berlin and Paris ...

*Source*: [Contested Spaces, Common Ground: Space and Power Structures in Contemporary Multireligious Societies](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=p9M6DQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA339&dq=Brussels%20halfway%20between%20Paris%20and%20Berlin&pg=PA339#v=onepage&q&f=false) (P339 - 340)

The Wikipedia article - [Brussels and the European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brussels_and_the_European_Union) - spells out why Brussels was chosen and points out there have been various major political tussles since the birth of EU on this:

> A Committee of Experts deemed Brussels to be the one option to have all the necessary features for a European capital: a large, active metropolis, without a congested centre or poor quality of housing; good communications with other member states' capitals, including to major commercial and maritime markets; vast internal transport links; an important international business centre; plentiful housing for European civil servants; and an open economy. Furthermore, it was located halfway between France and Germany (as in the case of other seats of European institutions), and on the border between the two major European civilisations: Latin and Germanic; and was at the centre of the first post-war integration experiment: the Benelux. As a capital of a small country, it also could not claim to use the presence of institutions to exert pressure on other member states, it being more of a neutral territory between the major European powers. The committee's report was approved of by the council, Parliament and Commissions ...

> The decision was put off due to the varied national positions preventing a unanimous decision. Luxembourg fought to keep the ECSC or have compensation; France fought for Strasbourg; Italy, initially backing Paris, fought for any Italian city to thwart Luxembourg and Strasbourg. Meanwhile, the Parliament passed a series of resolutions complaining about the whole situation of spreading itself across three cities, though unable to do anything about it.

Somewhere in central Europe, one may be able to find a similar location, like Brussels, that meets nearly all the criteria the EU considered before. But in all likelihood, now that the institutions of EU have been established and become entrenched, it is highly unlikely that a proposal to move them away from there will be welcome (especially when you consider the amount of political bickering that happened before on this subject, not to mention the wasteful cost it will incur to create new infrastructure).

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [EU institutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_seats_of_the_European_Union) has some interesting information on what is where. Some were established by specific treaty in specific locations (such as Europol). There have been attempts to put some bodies such as the Frontex border agency in Warsaw, but they've had problems getting staff, allegedly. You could look at where the population centre is as well: Germany, France, Italy, and Spain are the most populous nations.